# Getting text input into ivy completing read

Tags: ivy, completing-read

I know that I can get previous selections of ivy with ivy-history. But is there any way to get what was actually input into the search before choosing a match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the variable `ivy-text` has what you are looking for in it.

Comment: it does! thank you!